# Hiding status bar in iPhone but not in iPad

Tags: ios

I am building a universal iOS app. I want to hide the status bar in iPhone but I want to show the status bar in iPad. How do I achieve this. If I set the "Status bar is initially hidden" property to "YES" in info.plist, it is getting hidden in both iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following code to the method `- (BOOL)application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in your AppDelegate class.

```
if((void *)UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != NULL && UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
{
    //the device is iPad
    //no need of this anyhow since it is not hidden by default
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
} 
else 
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
}
```